# Web view did finish delegate method is not called in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am developing a product in which we have to render a web page. This particular web page can invoke our objective c methods. This is implemented using EasyJSWebview. Once the web page is loaded that has a timer running there. Web page is shown properly till the timer reaches the desintaiton time. Once that timer is reached, that page is reloaded with some event content. There the problem is occurred. The problem is that the page starts to load, activity indicator is shown but it does not close of finishing delegate method is not called. So, Activity Indicator is shown forever. But, Page is not loaded yet. But, If I navigate to the side menu and reload the page manually, That event web page is loaded properly and If I press home button when it reloads with the activity indicator, the app closes and I open it again, that activity indicator is hidden and the page is not loaded yet.

There are lots of hits to server during this event. It occurs only in live. But, If I test it in our development server with many hits with the help of JMeter, our application works properly.

So, It occurs only in live. Our live deployment consists of many replica's of servers. Can it occur due to this too?.

I am not able to find any solution for this. Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had an issue like Web view did finish delegate not getting loaded. It happened while loading videos using webView. In that, case the web view didFailLoadWithError was getting called with a error.

Comment: We should always add code to hide activity indicator in didFailLoadWithError.  Try whether this is getting called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just an internet issue. The present code works properly.